# how to re-update git branch and workflow improvement

Tags: git

So I have just started collaborating with someone using a git repository. We are pretty new to using git but understand the basics and have devised this workflow for the two of us.

3 branches: Master, User1, User2

We work separately on user1 or user2, and then when we complete the small task that we are working on individually we merge it back to the master branch and resolve any conflicts that there might be.

My question is, after one of us merges with master and resolve conflicts in master, what is the best way to make our respective user branch match master? Just close the branch and checkout a new one?

Also if there are any improvements to our workflow, advice would be greatly appreciated. Trying to get a full understanding of git, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always recreate your branch and start a new one based off of `master`. This is one of the cool things about git, that branches are cheap so you can make/delete as many as you want. I prefer doing something like this rather than maintaining long-running branches.

Another option is to `rebase` your branch onto master any time there are new commits in master. Rebasing is a concept that took me a little bit of time to grasp fully and it has a pitfall or two if not used properly, so read up before attempting this. It's very cool though!

My workflow for most projects typically involves just one branch, `master`. I do my work in "topic" branches, meaning I create a new branch for every distinct task I'm working on. When I'm done with that task I can merge it to `master` and then push so that other people can get those changes. I can then delete my topic branch safely.

If you're just starting out with git, this is a great resource: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: I think i might just merge the master branch into the user branch after this is done.. it called it fast-forward.. sounds like exactly what i am looking for. Are there any problems with doing it this way?

Comment: @TroyCosentino Not really, no. Personally, I find that merging bidirectionally (i.e. to master AND from master) clutters your history and makes things a bit hard to follow. Rebasing keeps things cleaner if you really want to keep one branch running at all times, but again, one of git's biggest draws is the ability to NOT do that. :)

Comment: @TroyCosentino No problem! Did I answer your question or are you still looking for a solution? :)